# Checking if value exists in a matrix and getting its columns

Tags: matlab

I have a 500x500 matrix with values ranging from 1-100.

I need to look at 5 rows at a time and see if those 5 rows contain values that are greater than 75. I then need to get the index of the first column where the value is greater than 75 and the index of the last column where the value is greater than 75.

So far, I have the following:

```
i = 1;
while i < size(data,1)

    if (i + 5) <= size(data,1)
        if any(envNoClutterscansV(i:i + 5, 1:500) > 75)
            % do something
        end
    end

    i = i + 5;
end
```

The idea here is that I am looking at 5 rows at a time. For every 5 rows, I'm looking through all the columns to see if there are values that meet my criteria. So far, this doesn't find any values, even though I'm sure that my dataset contains the values. Additionally, I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: I'll be training classifier later and I need data from multiple rows (in this case 5).

Comment: The algorithm that I'm going to be implementing needs 5 rows at a time

Comment: The code I've provided here is just an example, but you can assume that I'll be doing more in the line that says % do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks 5 rows a time. Use `find` to locate the values `> 75` and `ind2sub` to convert the indices returned by `find` to rows (ignored) and columns `cols`.

```
data = [
    11 76 25 44 55 78;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 88;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    ];


for row = 1:5:size(data, 1)
    fprintf('Row %d - %d\n', row, row+4);
    indices = find(data(row:row+4,:) > 75);

    if ~isempty(indices)
        [~, cols] = ind2sub([5 size(data, 2)], indices);

        col_min = min(cols);
        col_max = max(cols);

        fprintf('Column: %d and %d\n', col_min, col_max);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble might be that the result of any in the above code is a vector of 500 true and false values. You should sum them if you e=want to respond every time there are larger than 75 values:

```
if sum(any(envNoClutterscansV(i:i + 5, 1:500) > 75))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed it up, you can avoid the loop and vectorize it, for example like this:

```
data = [
    11 76 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 95 44 85 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 90 25 44 55 88;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    91 0 25 44 55 80;
    ];

% Geting the number of rows
nRows=size(data,1);
% Retting a logical matrix with all the cells that are above the treshold
cellsOverTreshold=data>75;
% Getting a logical index to all the rows that contain values above
% treshold
matchingRows=any(cellsOverTreshold,2);

% In nexy line of code "reshape" rearange the data to put in columns the
% values associated  to each goup of 5 rows
% So colum 1 have group one corresponding to data columns 1,2,3,4,5
%    colum 2 have group two corresponding to data columns 6,7,8,9,10
%    and so on

% Now we can get all the row groups that have velues above threshold
matchingRowGroups=find(any(reshape(matchingRows,5,[])));

% Now e put each row of on a cell array to be able to operate row-wise
cellRows = num2cell(cellsOverTreshold, 2);
% We now get the first and last column over the threshold for each row
firstColumOfRow = cellfun(@(x)find(x,1,'first'), cellRows,'UniformOutput',false);
lastColumOfRow = cellfun(@(x)find(x,1,'last'), cellRows,'UniformOutput',false);
% We replace the empty cells with NaNs so we can convert them to vectors
% without losing the indexing
firstColumOfRow(~matchingRows)={NaN};
lastColumOfRow(~matchingRows)={NaN};
% We rearrange the data as above and get the minimum of the first columns
% of each group, that is the first colum of the group above the threshold
firstColInGroup=nanmin(reshape([firstColumOfRow{:}]',5,[]));
% With the maximum of the last colums we get the last column of each group
lastColInGroup=nanmax(reshape([lastColumOfRow{:}]',5,[]));
% We finaly keep only the data of the groups with at that have at least one
% element above the threshold
firstColInGroup=firstColInGroup(matchingRowGroups);
lastColInGroup=lastColInGroup(matchingRowGroups);
```

In this way the variable "matchingRowGroups" have the indexes of each group of 5 rows that matchs. The variable "firstColInGroup" have the first column matching for each group and "lastColInGroup" the last one.

Comment: Using `cellfun` is not vectorisation. `cellfun` is a loop

Comment: @SardarUsama I agree, but it is still faster than a loop. I added two more solutions in separate answers, more compact than this one and with real vectorization.

Comment: `cellfun` is not what would make it faster (if it is any faster)

Comment: @SardarUsama Do the test yourself. cellfun is faster than a loop. Try for example: N=100000;
a=rand(N,30);
b = num2cell(a, 2);
c=zeros(size(a));

tic;
for i=1:N 
    c(i)=mean(a(i,:));
end
toc

tic;
c = cellfun(@mean, b,'UniformOutput',false);
toc

Comment: `tic toc` is for rough estimation of time. Use `timeit`.

Comment: @SardarUsama Sure, but doesn't make any difference in this case. A rough estimation is good enough because cellfun is quite a bit faster. If you want to overkill the problem and get the same answer try;

function comp
global x
N=100000;
a=rand(N,30);
x = num2cell(a, 2);

timeit(@f1)
timeit(@f2)

end
function c=f1
    global x
    c=zeros(length(x),1);
    for i=1:length(x)
        c(i)=mean(x{i});
    end
end

function c=f2
    global x
    c = cellfun(@mean, x,'UniformOutput',false);
end

Comment: `global` seriously! I have tried both ways and the loop is faster.

Comment: @SardarUsama perfect use of global for this application. Do you want to discuss whether cellfun is faster than a loop? or just criticize whatever you can on any piece of code? I haven't hear anything constructive from you.

Comment: it's the worst use. global is not needed at all. You should stop making it personal and keep it professional. All I have told you is the thing known to all MATLAB experts.

Comment: @SardarUsama OK, now please back with FACTS that cellfun us NOT faster than a for loop. As all MATLAB experts know.

Comment: Read the words from one of the most valued participant of Mathworks, Walter Robertson. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42335-array-cellfun-vs-for-loop and read the comment by Mathworks staff member, Sean de Wolski. If you find their words invalid/inaccurate then there is no point of arguing with you

Comment: @SardarUsama I did tests, and they show cellfun is faster. You can repeat the experiment yourself. But it seem like you rather keep your conviction and disregard the facts. Walter Robertson said "For loops are usually faster", not ALWAYS faster. Feel free to perform test for that particular case. Or if you find a flaw in my tests, that is relevant to the result and not just about style, please point it out.

Comment: I have done the test and the loop is faster.  It is faster or equally fast in all the cases involving numeric operations. Exceptions are strings/chars which is not the case here. Furthermore, you're trying to benchmark on a different code that's not relevant to the post. And using global variables is not just about the style. Please act like a professional and stop making this personal.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my previous answer, here is another option of vectorization, avoiding to transform data into cell arrays and avoiding using cellfun too, therefore, it is probably faster. Here it is:

```
data = [
    11 76 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 95 44 85 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 90 25 44 55 88;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    91 0 25 44 55 80;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 0 25 84 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    ];

% Geting the number of rows
[nRows, nCols]=size(data);
% Retting a logical matrix with all the cells that are above the treshold
cellsOverTreshold=data>75;
% Getting a logical index to all the rows that contain values above
% treshold
matchingRows=any(cellsOverTreshold,2);

% In nexy line of code "reshape" rearange the data to put in columns the
% values associated  to each goup of 5 rows
% So colum 1 have group one corresponding to data columns 1,2,3,4,5
%    colum 2 have group two corresponding to data columns 6,7,8,9,10
%    and so on

% Now we can get all the row groups that have velues above threshold
matchingRowGroups=find(any(reshape(matchingRows,5,[])))

%We find the rows and columns of all the first and last columns of each row
% that have values above threshold
[firstRow, firstCol]=find(cumsum(cumsum(cellsOverTreshold,2),2)==1);
[lastRow, lastCol]=find(cumsum(cumsum(cellsOverTreshold,2,'reverse'),2,'reverse')==1);
% Sort this data in vectors with one value per row, leaving NANs for rows
% with no element above threshold
firstColumOfRow=NaN(nRows,1);
lastColumOfRow=NaN(nRows,1);
firstColumOfRow(firstRow)=firstCol;
lastColumOfRow(lastRow)=lastCol;

% We rearrange the data as above and get the minimum of the first columns
% of each group, that is the first colum of the group above the threshold
firstColInGroup=nanmin(reshape(firstColumOfRow,5,[]));
% With the maximum of the last colums we get the last column of each group
lastColInGroup=nanmax(reshape(lastColumOfRow,5,[]));
% We finaly keep only the data of the groups with at that have at least one
% element above the threshold
firstColInGroup=firstColInGroup(matchingRowGroups)
lastColInGroup=lastColInGroup(matchingRowGroups)
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit more, here you have yet another simpler, faster and more compact solution. See my first solution for more datils on the naming of variables, but they are quite self explanatory

```
data = [
    11 76 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 95 44 85 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    11 90 25 44 55 88;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    91 0 25 44 55 80;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 75 25 44 55 75;
    11 0 25 84 55 0;
    11 0 25 44 55 0;
    ];

% Geting the number of rows and columns
[nRows, nCols]=size(data);

%We create arrays with rows and column numbers of each element
[colNum,rowNum]=meshgrid(1:nCols,1:nRows);
% Set NaN the column numbers that do not match the treshold
colNum(data<=75)=NaN;
% Get the group number of each element
groupNum=ceil(rowNum/5);

%The matching groups are those that have at least one non-NaN element
matchingRowGroups = accumarray(groupNum(:),colNum(:),[],@(x)any(~isnan(x)))
%We get the minimum of the column numbers matching thershold on each group
firstColumOfGroup = accumarray(groupNum(:),colNum(:),[],@nanmin)
%We get the maximum of the column numbers matching thershold on each group
lastColumOfGroup = accumarray(groupNum(:),colNum(:),[],@nanmax)
```

The only difference with the previous solutions is that matchingRowGroups is a logical index, and firstColumOfGroup and lastColumOfGroup have one entry per group, instead of entries only for groups with elements above the threshold. Groups with no entry above threshold have NaN values